# Spring Boot アプリケーションをライブラリ化する方法

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, spring-boot

Spring Boot でコマンドラインアプリケーションを作っていたのですが、急きょ、アプリではなくライブラリにしなければならなくなりました。

開発環境：Eclipse、Windows7
開発言語：Java
フレームワーク：Spring Boot

※以下、xxxxx.jarというのが私が作成したもの。

#### 現在の起動方法

1. 起動用batファイルでjavaコマンドを実施(java -cp xxxxx.jar xxx.xxx.MainClass)
2. xxxxx.jar起動

#### 変更後の起動方法

1. 既存アプリケーションに当該ライブラリの情報を設定（対象ファイル、クラス、メソッド）
2. 既存アプリケーションは当該ライブラリをロードして、設定されたクラスとメソッドを実行

Springフレームワークの機能を利用しつつ、このように移行することはできないでしょうか。
今現在、メインクラスのmainメソッドを削除し、executeというメソッドを作成して既存アプリに登録していますが、以下のエラーでうまく起動できていません。

```
Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [xxx.xxx.MainClass]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
```

フレームワークを利用してアプリを作る為の情報は山ほどありますが、フレームワークを利用してライブラリ（mainメソッドが無い）を作る方法はないのでしょうか。
その様なことは一般的にできないのでしょうか。

### 追記

試行錯誤した結果、上記エラーはなくなりました。
しかし、AutowiredアノテーションによるDIがされません。

Answer (score 1):

AutowiredでDIされなかったクラスは呼び出し元から`new`されたインスタンスでした。
その為、当該クラスをラップしたクラスにて目的のクラスを`ApplicatoinContext#getBean()`を利用してインスタンス生成するようにしたところ、DIされるようになりました。